# Get day and time as UTC of the current day and add its difference to a UTC timestamp

Tags: sql, impala

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable fact
JOIN time_table time ON ( time.time_5_min_utc = fact.event_5_min_utc )
WHERE fact.event_utc >= ${fromTimestamp}
  AND fact.event_utc < ${toTimestamp} 
  AND time.time_5_min_utc >= ${fromTimestamp} 
  AND time.time_5_min_utc < ${toTimestamp}
```

I always know the fromTimestamp in UTC.

What I want to to now is add value to toTimestamp to get the end of the day.

Something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable fact
JOIN time_table time ON ( time.time_5_min_utc = fact.event_5_min_utc )
WHERE fact.event_utc >= ${fromTimestamp}
  AND fact.event_utc < ${toTimestamp} + 86400000
  AND time.time_5_min_utc >= ${fromTimestamp} 
  AND time.time_5_min_utc < ${toTimestamp} + 86400000
```

This should add 86400000 to the toTimestamp but what I get is a +24h.
It should be the end of current day 23:59:59.

How can I do that?

Comment: you could possibly try this expression: DATEADD(second,-1, datediff(dd,0,${toTimestamp})+1). So you are getting the difference in number of days from beginning as DATE, adding a day and then subtracting one second from it.

Comment: @SharathNS this staement is not working. DATE_ADD only allows to be used like ```date_add(TIMESTAMP startdate, INT days)``` and 'dd' is not found in datediff, because datediff can only be used like ```datediff(TIMESTAMP enddate, TIMESTAMP startdate)```

Comment: i think you can compare date and remove time. So you dont need 23:59:59. Just TRUNC(Timestamp, 'DD') on both sides

Comment: @KoushikRoy I need to use the query as it is displayed in my question. This is restricted. I only can change what UTC timestamp I choose and just add something like '+86400000'.

Comment: Which Database are you using? As I understand instead of 86400000, you need an alternate number which would give the 23:59:59 of the totimestamp date. I assume the toTimestamp is a parameter you are getting, you could just update the time part to 23:59:59 keeping the datepart same for the query comparison: something like: $endDate = Date($totimeStamp)+23:59:59 and then use endDate for comparison. This is not the correct syntax, you would need to get the correct syntax by an internet search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way how to fix this problem and I wanted to share my solution.

```
CAST (
       to_utc_timestamp (
                 date_add (
                     date_add (
                         date_trunc (
                             'day',
                             CAST (
                                   CAST (
                                       ${toTimestamp} AS DECIMAL (30, 0))
                                 / 1000
                                     AS TIMESTAMP)),
                         1),
                       interval
                     - 1 seconds),
                 'myNeededTimezone')
                 AS BIGINT)
       * 1000
```

**Explanation:** 
First the 'toTimestamp is cast as decimal to be able to cast it as timestamp afterwards. When it is a timestamp it is possible to extract the day of it and then subtract 1 second to get the day before 23:59:59. Then it is converted back to a UTC timestamp with the correct timezone. At last it is converted back as number and multiplied with 1000 to get a UTC timestamp in milliseconds.